# Ruby on Rails Active Admin - Duplicate Records showing for HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am designing a basic file manager (the Asset model) in the Active Admin gem.  Each Asset HABTM Groups, and vice-versa.

In my active_admin Asset resource I have a filter where I want to be able to 
select multiple groups to filter by, so I added:

```
filter :groups_id, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc {Group.all}
```

All of the groups show up as checkboxes as expected.  However, if I have asset_1, asset_2 and I have group_1 assigned to asset_1 and asset_2, and group_2 to asset_2, when I 
filter by both roles, asset_2 lists itself twice.

How can I restrict the filter to use only "distinct" or "unique" assets to be returned?

I also have another problem, which is that the filters are not working at all in any of my scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

has_and_belongs_to_many accepts a `:uniq` option which ensures that only uniq records will be returned. Setting this in your model should do the trick.

```
class MyModel
  has_and_belongs_to_many :things, :uniq => true
end
```

Comment: Just gave that a whirl, and rebooted rails server, still having the same issue.  I added the :uniq option to both the Asset and Group models.

Comment: I don't mean to point fingers, as it's very possible I am doing something stupid simple wrong here, but this almost seems like a bug in ActiveAdmin??? Even if I have only 1 Asset, if I assign it to 2+ groups, and then tick the checkboxes for those 2+ groups in the filter sidebar, the 1 Asset will show up 2+ times.

See: http://i.imgur.com/GbntK.png

Comment: Yes, I believe this to be a bug with HABTM relationships in Active Admin at this point.  The checkboxes append `&q[groups_id_in][]=1&q[groups_id_in][]=2` to the query string params in the URL.  This seems to force a Assets.where(:group_id => 1) and Assets.where(:group_id => 2), thus returning the same entries multiple times.

Comment: why is this marked as the answer if the comments are indicating it didn't work? is there a AA issue on github for this? @professormeowingtons

Answer (score 5):

A quick update on Will's answer. I'm running Rails 5.0 and ActiveAdmin 1.0, and `clean_search_params` returned an error. But this worked instead:

```
def apply_filtering(chain)
  super
  @search.result(distinct: true)
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much!!
The next trick will be to figure out how to make that the default for all controllers ...

Answer (score 4):

Active admin read indicates to add

```
distinct: true
```

to get unique results.

To apply that to active admin, I'm using doing that like this:

```
controller do
  def apply_filtering(chain)
     @search = chain.ransack clean_search_params params[:q]
     @search.result(distinct: true)
   end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, although I don't think this feature existed in 2012 when I asked this question :(

Comment: no worries.  I put here partly for my own ref.  bound to come up quite often.

Comment: The latest version of ActiveAdmin removed the argument from `clean_search_params` method. So the line should now read `@search = chain.ransack clean_search_params`

Answer (score 1):

... and, a quick addition Alex's answer:

If you want to do this for all controllers in your app, you can add this to an initializer (mine's called `active_admin_patches.rb`) -

```rb
# This guarantees that the results for a filtered #index page search do not appear more than once, on any #index page in the AA app
# TODO: THIS WILL PROBABLY FAIL WITH SOME FUTURE UPDATE, SO BE READY TO UPDATE IT FROM THE LATEST GEM SOURCE
module ActiveAdmin::ResourceController::DataAccess
  # Applies any Ransack search methods to the currently scoped collection.
  # Both `search` and `ransack` are provided, but we use `ransack` to prevent conflicts.
  def apply_filtering(chain)
    @search = chain.ransack(params[:q] || {})
    # This is the original line
    # @search.result
    # This is the patch
    @search.result(distinct: true)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why anybody *wouldn't* want this to be the default behavior, but there's probably a reason.  Hmm, maybe for cases where a column of the index view is one of the non-distinct rows.  Yeah, that must be it.

Also, there's bound to be a better way to patch this less intrusively, but I'm in a hurry.  :-)